# library for Mongo() in nodejs

Tags: node.js, mongodb

I was able to run the following code in the my system but after rebooting, It is showing Mongo is not defined.
I copied the whole node_modules folder into new folder but nothing is helping, may be it was in cache and now its lost as i have clean the cache also.

```
mongo = new Mongo("localhost");
keywordsDb = mongo.getDB("database");
keywordsColl = keywordsDb.getCollection("keywords");
```

The log is below:

```
    (function (exports, require, module, __filename, __dirname) { mongo = new Mongo(
"localhost");
                                                                          ^

ReferenceError: Mongo is not defined
    at Object.<anonymous> (D:\js\restful\query.js:1:75)
    at Module._compile (module.js:434:26)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:452:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:355:32)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:310:12)
    at Function.Module.runMain (module.js:475:10)
    at startup (node.js:118:18)
    at node.js:952:3
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try to change the current directory to the root of your application and run the following command "npm install" and check if you have an error  message.

Also, you should use this syntax to connect your node.js app to mongodb:

```
var MongoClient = require('mongodb').MongoClient;
var keywordsDb;
var keywordsColl;

MongoClient.connect('mongodb://localhost:27017/database', function(err, database) {
    if (err) throw err;
    keywordsDb = database;
    keywordsColl = keywordsDb.getCollection("keywords");
});
```

Comment: I did it but the problem is I have not mentioned my dependency in package.json, when i was working on it I tried too many things that i don't remember how i made that run. I have just begin MongoDb and node.js and yesterday i did not even have any idea of package.json

Comment: In the node_modules directory, check the name of the subdirectories you find in it. It is the name of the package you have installed.

Just try to reinstall the package with a "npm packagename --save" and it will update your package.json file